# Is there way to test below code using sinon

Tags: javascript, sinon, meld

```
meld.before(myObject, 'doSomething', function(x) {
    console.log(2);
});
```

did any one tried writing test case for above code statement.

Using meld.js library and sinon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It is just about calling this method

```
call (myObject.doSomething)  it logs 2 and your log
```

remove behavior

```
var rem = meld.before(myObject, 'doSomething', function(x) {
    console.log(2);
}); 

rem.remove();

now call again (myObject.doSomething)  // just logs normal log
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding sinon, you could use the various interceptors (mocks, spies, etc).

But I'm interested in your second statement:

**did any one tried writing test case for above code statement**

Yes, the meld dev team has. You can test the meld API exactly the same way the meld dev team tests the same API call. That working code from the repository can be found here:

https://github.com/cujojs/meld/blob/master/test/before.js

Although this is not using Sinon, it does answer your (intended?) question.